# How do I use a user Hexadecimal input as a turtle color?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm in an Intro CSci course and I honestly have no background in coding at all, one of our assignments is to have the user input a Hexadecimal code that changes the color of the turtle, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
usernumber = input("Please enter a 6-digit Hexadecimal number: ")

import turtle
suga = turtle.Turtle()
suga.shape('turtle')
suga.color("#usernumber")

for i in range(4):
    suga.left(90)
    suga.forward(100)
    suga.stamp()
```

This is what I have, everything works other than the turtle color. The assignment says I have to include the hashtag for the Hexadeci, but I don't know how to input the usernumber as the color. It never works.

Literally ignore if I made stupid mistakes, I genuinely know nothing, nada, about code so. And yes my turtle is named after a BTS member.

Comment: Use `suga.color('#%s'% usernumber)` and will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your line:

```
suga.color("#usernumber")
```

To

```
suga.color(usernumber)
```

Or if the user isn't expected to add the `#` character themselves, then you could do:

```
suga.color('#' + usernumber)
```

`"#usernumber"` is a literal string. `usernumber` is the variable containing the input from the user from your call to `input()` on the first line.

Comment: You probably need to prepend the #, unless the user enters it